# JS heap size increases gradually in the Performance monitor

Tags: reactjs

While dynamically creating and destroying React's standard components (such as Button, Div, etc.) from the DOM using the React state, I observed a gradual increase in the JS heap size, which is monitored in the browser's Performance monitor.

May I know the reason why the JS heap size has increased? And how to retain its initial state when the component is destroyed?

I have tried with the code-snippet below along with screenshots:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'

let Data: any[] = [
  {
    RegisterNo: 910318104022,
    Name: "Jack",
    Department: "CSE",
    Batch: 2018,
    CollegeName: "CCET"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState<number[]>([])

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(v => [...v, 1])}>add</button>
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(v => v.slice(1))}>remove</button>
      <ul>
      {visible.map((t, i) => {
        t;
        return <li key={i}><Table /></li>
      })}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default App


function Table () {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        {Object.keys(Data[0]).map((column, i) => <td key={i}>{column}</td>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {OrderData.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>
              {Object.values(item).map((row, j) => <td key={j}>{row as any}</td>)}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

[Initial snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jqHI.png)

Add and remove LI elements multiple times, then collect garbage and take another snapshot

[Final snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q22XI.png)

The difference between the initial and final snapshots is described below:

**JS heap size**        :   0.8 MB

**DOM Nodes**       :   0

**JS event listeners**  :   0